# Fix for gibberish characters

Tags: windows, character-encoding

I receive emails (via hotmail mostly) with files from a few users with weird characters in the name of the file and folders. What steps do I have to take to prevent this happen again?

Edit: It is in Greek.

Here is a sample:
[image]

Comment: Are these legitimate emails? Or spam?

Comment: @DavidPostill, good point.These are legitimate emails, coming from known to me people.

Answer (score 1):

Are they from any noticeably 'foreign' part of the world, i.e., non-'english' characters being used?
You may just be missing the Language Pack, especially if that's on Win 10, which doesn't include them by default.

**[How to add an input language to your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/how-to-add-an-input-language-to-your-pc#v1h=tab01)**
Applies to Windows 10

1. Go to Settings > Time & language > Region & language.
2. Select Add a language.
3. Select the language you want to use from the list, then choose which region's version you want to use. Your download will begin immediately.

Comment: possibly, they are missing this, not me, as I do receive other files in Greek in the right format and I have already installed the language as you describe. I m going to check this up with them.

Comment: Then perhaps it is Hotmail garbling them instead. Get them to zip the files before transmission